# T-SQL Subquery Return Column Results

Tags: t-sql, correlated-subquery

I need to return information from a column that is specified in a subquery.
In the subquery below,  I am trying to return info from the PaymentDate column.
When I try to Select Order.PaymentDate in my query I get an error `Invalid object name` for the `Order.PaymentDate`.  I tried to specify this as Payment.PaymentDate but I get the same error. 
Any idea on how I can fix this?

```
(SELECT ID, SUM(amount) AS purchase FROM Order
WHERE Order.PaymentDate BETWEEN '2012-09-01' AND '2012-09-04'
AND Order.amount >=0
    GROUP BY ID)Payment
```

Comment: If you want to select a column from a sub query, that column must be in the sub queries select statement.

Comment: I did specify the column in the subquery select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the order.payment date available in an outer query, you'll need to `group by` it, but I doubt that's what you want.  Do you want an aggregate function, like `max(order.payment)` or `min(order.payment)`?  You can't mix aggregate and non-aggregate functions in the same query.

If what you want, as you say in a comment to another answer, is to validate your date range criteria was applied, return the max() and min() range of values, like:

```
 (SELECT ID, SUM(amount) AS purchase, 
min(order.paymentdate) as min_payment, 
max(order.paymentdate) as max_payment 
FROM Order
    WHERE Order.PaymentDate BETWEEN '2012-09-01' AND '2012-09-04'
    AND Order.amount >=0
        GROUP BY ID)Payment
```

Comment: For the payments I just need to display the date the order was placed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the aggregate of a date range, there isn't any specfic dates in any of the returned rows of your subquery.  You can always arbitrally state the date range in the outer query to show the date range that the aggregate is summing.

```
SELECT Payment.ID, Payment.purchase, '2012-09-01' AS 'startdate', '2012-09-04' AS 'enddate' 
FROM (SELECT ID, SUM(amount) AS purchase 
     FROM Order 
     WHERE Order.PaymentDate BETWEEN '2012-09-01' AND '2012-09-04' 
     AND Order.amount >=0 
     GROUP BY ID) AS Payment
```

Comment: I am guessing that is one way of doing this but I am not sure it is what I am looking for.  I have the query working fine, I just need to validate that I am only returning the orders from the dates specified in the subquery.

Comment: Limey was right.  I was missing the reference to column in the Subquery.  Here is what worked: SELECT Orders.PaymentDate as [Payment Date]

(SELECT ID, Orders.PaymentDate AS PaymentDate,
WHERE Orders.PaymentDate BETWEEN '2012-09-01' AND '2012-09-04'
AND Orders.Amount >=0
GROUP BY mbrs_ky, Orders.PaymentDate)Payment